# Oracle Regular Expressions using Wildcards

Tags: regex, performance, oracle

Would using the wildcard regular expression in a REGEXP_LIKE be less performant than not including the condition clause at all.

For example, I want to create an Oracle prepared statement like the one below:

```
select * from table_name 
where regexp_like(column1, ?)
and regexp_like(column2, ?)
and regexp_like(column3, ?)
and regexp_like(column4, ?)
```

The query may not need to specify a criteria for all the columns.  For those columns with no criteria, we can use the wildcard regular expression * **OR** we can simply not include the condition from the where clause.

```
select * from table_name 
where regexp_like(column1, 'h[i|ello]')
and regexp_like(column2, '.*')
and regexp_like(column3, '.*')
and regexp_like(column4, 'bye')
```

**OR**

```
select * from table_name 
where regexp_like(column1, 'h[i|ello]')
and regexp_like(column4, 'bye')
```

Would using the wildcard character in the regexp_like condition be less performant than simply not including the condition at all?  If so, would it be a significant performance difference?

The underlying concern is that a single sql statement can be used instead of having to dynamically create a sql statement according to the specified criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the optimizer chooses to do a full table scan as soon as it sees a `where .. regexp_like`, and so, I would assume that any performance impacts are negligible, regardless of how howmany `regexp_like` you have in your where condition.